# TextView going out of screen with constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using `ConstraintLayout` to create below xml in my application.
As you can see my first item is fine, But in the second one, some parts of my `textView` are not on the screen!

This is my `XML` code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ly_user"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/im_user_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/default_message_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_message_icon_size"
            android:src="@drawable/user_pacific"/>

    <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/im_user_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/im_user_icon"
            android:id="@+id/im_user_arrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_bg1"/>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/view_user_guidLine"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/im_user_arrow"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/im_user_arrow"/>

    <TextView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/im_user_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view_user_guidLine"
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/default_message_textarea_width"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/default_message_textarea_height"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_right_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I Know I can fix this problem to adding below line to the `textView`, But I need my `textView` be `wrapContent`.

```
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should align the container of the text view according to width. If that is done, then, TextView should fit in correctly.

Comment: Using maxWidth you can do this. I see already you applied but it should work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can set your `TextView's` width to `wrap_content`, but to prevent it from expanding outside of screen you need to add the left constraint as well and use `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to enforce constraints.

Now, to make the `TextView` stick to the right, you need to add `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"`, which will align it to its right constraint.

So all in all, these are the changes needed for the `TextView`:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to stop my view from extending itself past the views that constrained it.

Answer (score 4):

Add these following  line in your code in your `TextView`

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
```

first line `layout_constraintWidth_percent` is 60 percent of your phone screen width you can change it according to your need.

Comment: this works but all the time takes 0.6 of screen, But I want it to be wrap_content

Comment: I know, But I need my textView be wrap content all the time

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answered works but on my side I use `android:layout_width="0dp"` because my TextView is in the middle of two elements.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_id_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/long_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second_vertical_divider_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first_vertical_divider_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer didn't helped in my case. Alternative solution can look like that:

```
<ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/title"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ellipsize="end"
         android:maxLines="2"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/option_info"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap" />

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/option_info"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

The idea is to prevent one view pushing another while expanding by creating a chain and add some constraint params to hold influenced view in view's border.
Hope it still will help somebody!